# hector_imu_attitude_to_tf vs hector_localization

Tags: slam, imu, navigation, hector-localization, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using an IMU and a laser scanner and would like to create a planar map, but estimate the pose with 6DoF, for example for handheld mapping.

As far as I can see, it is not possible to estimate the height (z-axis value) with the available sensors, hence 5DoF remain.

My question now is: According to the `hector_mapping` tutorial ([here](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot)), it is possible to calculate the roll and pitch angles and broadcast the resulting transform between `base_stabilized` and `base_link` with `hector_imu_attitude_to_tf`.
On the other hand, the package `hector_pose_estimation` within `hector_localization` apparently takes the pose estimate from `hector_mapping` on `/poseupdate`, fuses it with the IMU data and publishes the 6DoF pose.

So, are there any advantages/differences when taking `hector_pose_estimation` instead of `hector_imu_attitude_to_tf` for example for performing 2D handheld SLAM, or is it just the same?
Is `hector_pose_estimation` maybe capable of doing something else that I miss (looking at the source code it seems to be pretty complex)?

Thanks,
Philipp

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256615/hector_imu_attitude_to_tf-vs-hector_localization/) by [pschroeppel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29637/pschroeppel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi
can you do this ???

i do this, i fuse imu and Z to localization but when i fused poseupdate from hector_mappin, localization gonna to jumping around...

---

Originally posted by [Morid_92](https://answers.ros.org/users/29279/morid_92/) with karma: 16 on 2017-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Morid_92](https://answers.ros.org/users/29279/morid_92/) on 2017-03-15**:
you don't need hector_imu_attitude_to_tf, because you can use /imu_raw topic in hector_pose_estimation and fusion the imu data to tf

and

you can fusion the height by publish z value on /height topic in hector_pose_estimation